# How to filter two data set from one selection in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a small application in `VueJs 2.0` where I'm having two select options with `Select2` plugin as such:

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Categories:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <v-select multiple :options="selectTable" placeholder="Categories"  v-model="categories"></v-select>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sub-Categories:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <v-select multiple :options="selectSubtractedTable" placeholder="Subtracted Categories"  v-model="subtractedCategories"></v-select>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now I've a computed property to list these elements inside, like:

```
computed: {
    selectTable() {
        if(this.model)
        {
            return this.model.map(a => ({
                value: a.id,
                label: a.name
            }));
        }
    },
    selectSubtractedTable() {
        if(this.subModel)
        {
            return this.subModel.map(a => ({
                value: a.id,
                label: a.name
            }));
        }
    }
},
```

Now I'm having a watch function which checks the first list and remove the elements from the second list as:

```
watch: {
    categories(newValue) {
        this.subModel = this.model
        for(var i = 0; i<newValue.length; i++ )
        {
            const element = this.subModel.find(a => a.id == newValue[i].value)
            console.log(element)
            if(element>0)
                this.subModel.splice(index, 1)
        }
    }
}
```

I've data set in following format:

```
this.model = this.subModel = [
    {
        "id":1,"name":"Jeans","created_at":null,"updated_at":null
    },
    {
        "id":2,"name":"Shirts","created_at":null,"updated_at":null
    },
    {
        "id":3,"name":"Top","created_at":null,"updated_at":null
    },
    {
        "id":4,"name":"Women","created_at":null,"updated_at":null
    },
    {
        "id":5,"name":"Men","created_at":null,"updated_at":null
    },
    {
        "id":6,"name":"Jwellary","created_at":null,"updated_at":null
    }
]
```

and `const element = this.subModel.find(a => a.id == newValue[i].value)` this is always showing value 0 in the watch property

Help me out.

Comment: `model` and `subModel` are the same object. When you delete from either, the other will be affected because they are the same object.

Comment: @RoyJ But initially both of them have same list, is there any way out?

Comment: You could start by copying: `this.subModel = this.model.slice()`.